# what is attr 'gtbfieldid' and how to avoid autocomplete behavior?

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-forms

I have this simple form:

```
class PagoDesde(forms.Form):
    from django import forms as f
    desde = f.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])
```

In my template:

```
    {{ form.desde }}
```

And has associated a jqueryui.datepicker in the document.ready

```
    $("#id_desde").datepicker();
```

The html result is:

```
<input type="text" id="id_desde" name="desde" 
class="hasDatepicker" gtbfieldid="598"/>
```

And it works great, but I have

2 questions:

- what is `gtbfieldid="598"`? does jquery add that?
- how to avoid the autocomplete behavior of the browsers in this textfield?

thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The `gtbfieldid` attribute is added dynamically by the Google Toolbar to the `<input>` and `<select>` tags that it thinks it can fill in for you.
2. If you add the `autocomplete="off"` attribute to the `<form>` tag that contains them, then the Google Toolbar will not add these `gtbfielid` attributes, and its autofill functionality will not be available when filling out that form.

Both of these attributes are non-standard XHTML, so your form will fail validation but if this autofill behavior is causing problems for your visitors, then adding the `autocomplete="off"` attribute is the only workaround to stop the Google Toolbar from manipulating your form elements and offering to try to fill it in for the user.

Here's how you'd set the autocomplete attribute (in django):

```
class PagoDesde(forms.Form):
    from django import forms as f
    desde = f.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
                        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}))
```

Comment: I just wanted to add my editorial comment, google should be shot in the face for not expanding the g to 'google'. What a waste of time. On the flip side, FF should be shot in the face for not coloring the attribute differently or indicating that it was added through script.